# margin is not working properly in windows/IE

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

I am using fedora/mozilla for my development enviorment.
I am using

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

to align a content in a center but it's not working on windows/IE8. while it is working properly on All other browser for Fedora, Window, Mac.

Regards,

Salil Gaikwad

Comment: Exact duplicate; read the first answer here.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/662341/using-margin-0-auto-in-internet-explorer-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using a DOCTYPE that that triggers Standards-Mode in IE (e.g. HTML Strict or HTML Transitional **with** DTD-Path)?