# Centering DIV with IE

Tags: css

I am trying to center a DIV, with `"margin:auto"` . It works fine with Chrome and FF but the following code does not center the DIV with IE:

CSS

```
#container {
 margin:auto;
 width:950px;
 height:50px;
 background:#000;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,

Joel

---

Edit (full HTML/CSS code):

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.2.0/build/cssreset/reset-min.css">
<style>

#container {
 margin: 0 auto; 
 width:950px;
 height:50px;
 background:#000;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which version of IE have you tested this code with? I normally define a `width` and then set `margin:0 auto` and it works fine even in IE...

Comment: Tried testing it with IE9! The code I used above...

Comment: True, but as Sime said use margin: 0 auto; You only have margin:auto

Comment: I get the same results... i am editing the original post with the full HTML code. Maybe you can run it on IE9 and tell me if it is also aligned to the left on your end.

Comment: `margin:0 auto;` simply states that the top and bottom margins should be zero pixels.  The auto refers to horizontal margins, which would be centered in this case.

Comment: Probably you can find you answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/662341/using-margin-0-auto-in-internet-explorer-8

Answer (score 18):

Insert this at the top of the document:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

or for `html5`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

[Reference for document type declaration](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp)

Answer (score 7):

**Margin Auto Centering**

Problem: When centering div tags via either the margin-left: auto; or margin-right: auto; settings, this will not work in Internet explorer unless you add the following to your style sheet for the html body:

```
html, body {
 text-align: center;
}
```

Don't forget to now add this to your paragraphs and headings as the above setting will now cause these to also center.

```
p {text-align: left;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this;

```
#container {
 margin:0 auto;
 width:950px;
 height:50px;
 background:#000;
}
```

Comment: Using margin: 0 auto; makes not a shred of difference

Comment: @Alex Be careful, I wouldn't be surprised if this change would make a difference in IE. IE has lots of weird bugs

Comment: Trust me, it's not. It's because the poster most likely doesn't have a valid doctype. Although I do understand where you are coming from having dealt with plenty of IE bugs in my time!

Answer (score 1):

You need to reference the doctype as mentioned by '2astalavista'

Otherwise

1.Center using positioning and negative margin if it is a known width

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.2.0/build/cssreset/reset-min.css">
<style>


#container {
position: relative;
left: 50%; 
margin: 0 0 0 -475px; /* negative margin of half the width */
width:950px;
height:50px;
background:#000;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

2.Use the outercontainer and text-align center to centre the element:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.2.0/build/cssreset/reset-min.css">
 <style>

#outerContainer{
text-align: center;
}

#container {
margin: 0 auto; 
width:950px;
height:50px;
background:#000;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="outerContainer">
      <div id="container"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This one worked for me:

```
#container {
   width: 80%; /* or the width of the object inside the container */
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help you out:

```
body {
    text-align: center;
}

#container {
    text-align: left;
    margin:auto;
    width:950px;
    height:50px;
    background:#000;
}
```

You do nothing wrong, IE6 does: it ignores "margin: auto;"

Comment: This method hasn't been required since IE5.5 I believe. Auto margins have always working in IE... it's just a case of making sure the browser isn't rendering in Quirks Mode.

Comment: IE9? maybe next time you have to say you're talking about IE9.

Answer (score 0):

You should put right & left attributes in there also:

```
#container
{
  right: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 950px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me with regards with the IE centering bug:

```html
<div style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: 50%;">
      <div style="text-align: left; margin: 1em auto; width: 50%;">
       

          <form action="/action_page.php">
            First name:<br>
            <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Tom">
            <br>
            Last name:<br>
            <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Cruise">
            <br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
          </form> 

      </div>
</div>
```