# Centering a div inside of another div

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a simple layout that consists of a `#container` with

```
#container {
    width: 775px;
    margin: 0 auto; 
}
```

to center it on the page with a maximum width of 775px

Then inside of that I have another `div` whose width varies depending on the content inside of it

```
.innerdiv { margin: 0 auto; }
```

I want it so if the `.innerdiv` is less than 775px, it will center within that 775px region.

The problem is that the above code is not working. I've wrestled with it for a bit but can't figure out what I need to do to accomplish this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-center-div-in-div try this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write like this:

```
#container {
    width: 775px;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    text-align:center;
}
.innerdiv {
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline /* IE */
    *zoom:1;/* IE */
    text-align:left;
}
```

Check this

### http://jsfiddle.net/efEgq/

Comment: ah, yes this works great! I didn't realize text-align worked that way, I always thought it was just the workaround to get divs centered correctly in older IE versions

Answer (score 2):

[Using “margin: 0 auto;” in Internet Explorer 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662341/using-margin-0-auto-in-internet-explorer-8)

> ...“margin: 0 auto” centers a block, but only when width of the block is set to be less that width of parent.

Answer (score 1):

To align a div to center.. use `margin: 0 auto;` but you must specify the width attribute of the . `width: 400px;` that must be less than the parent `container <div>`

for more information follow this [link](http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/center/) [Link](http://www.webcredible.co.uk/user-friendly-resources/css/css-tricks.shtml)

Answer (score 0):

Give relative position to #container

```
#container {
    width: 775px;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    position:relative;
}
```

try this.

Answer (score -6):

Just write `align="center"` for `innerdiv`.