# :before pseudo element won’t center in IE8 (Internet Explorer 8)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, alignment

I’ve created an element a `h4` element which the `:before` pseudo element to insert an icon font (generated at **IcoMoon**). The `h4` element is set to `text-align: center;` and the icons are set to `display: block;` so that they also center. Perfect!

The problem is in IE8. The `h4` elements are centered but the icons inserted using `:before` are left-aligned. I’ve tried giving the before element a `text-align: center` property and I also tried applying:

```
display: block;
width: 80px;
margin: 0 auto;
```

Now I don’t know what to try next. Here is the code for the icons:

```
[class^="ico-fonts-"]:before, 
[class*=" ico-fonts-"]:before {
    font-family: @icoFont;
    font-style: normal;
    speak: none;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1;
}
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated! :-)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/662341/using-margin-0-auto-in-internet-explorer-8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found the answer to my own question and it’s this:

*Internet Explorer 8* treats the content generated by the :before and :after **as outside of the element**.

However, all other browsers (except *IE7*) treat the content generated by the :before and :after pseudo-elements **as part of the element**.

So I simply had to write:

`.ico-fonts:before {
   text-align: center~"\9";
   }`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding zoom:1 yet? Fixes a lot of IE8 CSS quirks.

Comment: yep, tried that and it didn’t work. I’m testing in BrowserStack so I’m hoping that’s a true representation.

Comment: IE8 doesn’t actually use the hasLayout property, so using the zoom: 1; hack is pointless as it will do nothing. However, IE7 and below do have the hasLayout property, so feel free to use it to solve your hacks in these browsers.