# Navbar Centered In FF 22 Chrome 27 but Not IE 8

Tags: css, html, navigation

My Navigation bar is centered and works perfectly in Firefox 22 and Chrome 27 but not IE 8, I hate to be that guy but what gives?? Wouldn't it be great if everything just played nice, if this wasn't work related I wouldn't care, but we are stuck using IE. Is there some kind of resource for cross-browser compatibility or is it just trial by fire??

**CSS Markup**

```
body
{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.container
{
    width: 1004px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
.navigation
{
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
}
.navigation li
{
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    position: relative;
}
.navigation li a
{
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 7px 8px 7px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-top: 1px solid #F2861D;
    background: #262626;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.navigation li a:hover
{
    color: #F2861D;
}
.navigation ul
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
    margin: 0 0 0 -1px;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #F2861D;
}
.navigation ul li
{
    width: 150px;
    border-top: none;
}
.navigation ul a
{
    display: block;
    height: 15px;
    padding: 8px 7px 13px 7px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #6B6B6B;
}
.navigation ul a:hover
{
    color: #F2861D;
}
```

**HTML Markup**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="navigation">
        MY NAVIGATION
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this in the top of document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Or, if possible:

```
.container{
   width:100%; //auto
   margin:0 auto;
   text-align:center;
}
```

*Related question:*

[Using "margin: 0 auto;" in Internet Explorer 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662341/using-margin-0-auto-in-internet-explorer-8)

Comment: Ok I've added to the top of the document and my navbar is still on the left side of the page rather than centered, any other thoughts?? 
Changing the width to 100% doesn't seem to have any effect either, but thank you for the reply.

Comment: @DrewG just add the doctype, copy and paste the code here: http://htmledit.squarefree.com/ - you will see

Comment: It looks fine when it displays in the real time HTML editor, however that doesn't explain why its stuck on the left hand side when loaded in my IE 8 browser

Comment: I'm running 8, I tried on another machine running 6 and both look the same, I don't see how it can look right for you??

Comment: @DrewG See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/662341/using-margin-0-auto-in-internet-explorer-8 . Your problem is the same.