# Absolute Centering Not Working in IE

Tags: html, css

I have a div which is centered in parent div, it working on all browser but not in ie, can you help me out with this.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bkH9n/embedded/result/)

[image]

```
span.qbg3 {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    background: url(http://powerblanket.com/may2014/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/qbg3.png) no-repeat center center;
    background-size:cover;
    padding: 50px 20px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 30px;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -20px;
    min-height: 350px;
}
span.inqbg3 {
    max-height: 100px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    max-width: 700px;
    padding: 35px 0;
}
span.inqbg3 a {
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Hey i think this should help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/662341/using-margin-0-auto-in-internet-explorer-8 i think looking at your code you dont want to hardcode top and left values ??? am i right ?

Comment: @VikasGhodke: That's information you should edit into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/bkH9n/3/)</kbd>

You need to set `width` of the `span.inqbg3` as

`width: 100% /* Set your own height: percents, ems, whatever! */`

CSS

```
span.inqbg3 {
    height: 100%; /* Set your own height: percents, ems, whatever! */
    max-height: 100px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    width: 100%; /* Set your own width: percents, ems, whatever! */
    max-width: 700px;
    padding: 35px 0;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your css

Need to remove `right: 0` and `bottom: 0`

and change `left: 0` and `top: 0` to `left: 50%` and `top: 50%` and half minus height and width margin to bring it in center.

CSS

```
span.inqbg3 {
    max-height: 100px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 40px;
position: absolute;
margin:  -85px 0 0 -267px;
top: 50%;
/* right: 0; */
left: 50%;
/* bottom: 0px; */
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    max-width: 700px;
    padding: 35px;
}
```

[Here is the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bkH9n/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Remove position: absolute; from span.inqbg3 .