# Centering modals that work in IE8

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup, modal-dialog

I am trying to center my modals and I have the following code http://jsfiddle.net/be34jkzk/4/

That is the code I have. I just want to make sure that the modal is centered and kinda responsive. I tried changing the code for modalPopupClass to something like this, but it displays it weird on IE8.

CSS:

```
.modalPopupClass{
    display:none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    max-width: 630px;
    min-width: 320px;
    height: auto;
    z-index: 4020;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    }
```

Comment: `transform` won't work in IE8...AFAIK.

Comment: PS: I added the javascript as an in-line script and at least there's no more console errors: http://jsfiddle.net/be34jkzk/2/

Comment: [Big red block for transform in IE8 on caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=transform)

Comment: Here's some useful stuff on centering divs in IE8: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/662341/using-margin-0-auto-in-internet-explorer-8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a technique to keep a fluid height and width div dead center vertically and horizontally. Compatible in IE8+

- This is made possible with the combination of `margin: auto` and a tug-of-war between `top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0;` and  `right: 0;`
- Use a percentage width and height (it needs a height)
- Use a combination of min / max width and min / max height

Experiment to get the best results for your project.

[Here is a write up on the technique over on Smashing Magazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/09/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/)

CSS / HTML / Demo

```css
.dead-center {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background: #F00;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  min-width: 100px;
  min-height: 100px
}
```

```html
<div class="dead-center"></div>
```