# How to align center div element

Tags: html, css

I have some layout design,

And i want to align the div with id:#middle to center.

I put the background color to green on this div.

also i want to remain current state of layout like scroll bars, size, etc, ...

What is the best way to implement this?

I attached snippet of my code and jsfiddle as below.

**JSFiddles: https://jsfiddle.net/crisply/yr8he13g/8/**

Please refer this and give me some advices.

Thank you in advance.

```
<body>
<form method="post" action="./" id="form1" class="AspForm">

    <div id="header">
        <div id="top">
            <div id="logo">
                Logo
            </div>
            <div id="pageInfo">
                <div id="pageTitle">Title</div>
                <div id="pageDesc">Description</div>
                <div id="samplingInfo">Informations</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="menu">
            Menu
        </div>
    </div>


    <div id="content">
        <div id="middle">
            contents
       </div>
    </div>


    <div id="footer">
        <div id="copyright">
            Copyright &copy; 2015 eZRobotics. All rights reserved.
        </div>

        <div id="loginState">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top">
                        <div id="username">admin</div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        logout btn
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>    
</form>
</body>
```

here is css

```
html, body {
    /*font-size: 12px;*/
    font-family:'Tahoma', 'Segoe UI', Verdana !important;
}
body {
    height:100%;
}
div {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
/* -- header ----------------------------------------------- */
 #header {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    height:90px;
    /* TOP height + menu height*/
}
#top {
    height: 60px;
}
#logo {
    padding: 15px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 200px;
}
/* Title & sampling information */
 #pageInfo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align:central;
}
#pageTitle {
    font-size: 23px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Tahoma, 'Segoe UI', Verdana;
}
#pageDesc {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #666;
}
#samplingInfo {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 13px;
}
#menu {
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #666666;
    text-align: center;
}
/* -- ccontent ----------------------------------------------- */
 #content {
    top:90px;
    /* header height */
    bottom:24px;
    /* Footer height */
}
/* content */
 #left {
    position:absolute;
    top: inherit;
    /* header height */
    bottom: inherit;
    left:0;
    width:200px;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
#right {
    overflow:auto;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    position:absolute;
    top: inherit;
    /* header height */
    bottom: inherit;
    left:200px;
    right:0;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 0px;
}
#middle {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    position:absolute;
    top: inherit;
    bottom: inherit;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    max-width: 940px;
    background-color: green;
}
/* -- footer ----------------------------------------------- */
 #footer {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    height:24px;
    line-height: 24px;

    overflow:hidden;
    background-color: #666666;
    color: #eee;
    font-size: 13px;
}
#copyright {
    text-align: right;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    /*background-color: blue;*/
}
#loginState {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    /*background-color: green;*/
}
#username {
    border: 1px solid #C5C5C5;
    height: 18px !important;
    line-height: 18px;
    font-size:13px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
/* Table */
 .tbl {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    /*border:1px solid #000;*/
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
.tbl th, td {
    /* border:1px solid #000; */
}
.tbl th {
    background-color:#eee;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to align a <div> to the middle of the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/953918/how-to-align-a-div-to-the-middle-of-the-page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***CSS***

```
#middle {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: absolute;
  top: inherit;
  bottom: inherit;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  max-width: 940px;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/yr8he13g/10/)

Comment: Thank you for you answer, I have one more question.

Comment: I add margin: 0 auto; to middle css, But it does'nt work in IE (work well on firefox and chrome). How can i fix this??

Comment: @user2423434 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/662341/using-margin-0-auto-in-internet-explorer-8 check this out.

Comment: Could you please edit my sample code to work well on ie?... I did't not understand the concept of the link that you gave me...

Comment: @user2423434 for this to work fine u need to specify `width:some-value in px or %` in the `#middle.` https://jsfiddle.net/yr8he13g/26/

Comment: Hmm.. I do not want to fix the size of width,
If the width is fixed, When you reduce the width of the browser, horizontal scroll bar appears in the browser not on middle div.
I want to remain this unfixed width css.
Is there another solution?..
Thank you so much for you help.

Please refer my edited jsfiddles (https://jsfiddle.net/yr8he13g/29/)

Answer (score 1):

Just add `margin: 0 auto` to `#middle` [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/yr8he13g/11/embedded/result/)

```
#middle {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: absolute;
  top: inherit;
  bottom: inherit;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  max-width: 940px;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try -

```
#middle{
  text-align: center;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try `text-align:center;` for your #middle

Answer (score 0):

Add this lines at the bottom of your css, It will work

```
@media screen and (min-width: 940px){
    #middle {
        left:calc(50% - 470px);
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7aL3v56d/embedded/result/